Index error with moviepy when running on aws
I am getting this error:
"MoviePy error: failed to read the duration of file %s.\n"
OSError: MoviePy error: failed to read the duration of file https://delivery.gettyimages.com/downloads/1490392845?k=20&e=AnE-X_nyTRBG5QvUm1OnnCZEOURkdWAdDeQJTmDW8Eo41FL7u_ROCopEha5N-Kwh-fxBr44QIe5s2vzAUchlcVs91TwSlJTMOKWYSTraamKCPRcJv19CqNZRB_FgLaW_.
The funny thing is that for the same line of code:
video_duration = VideoFileClip(getty_url).duration

when running on my mac, it is running fine. However when running from an aws server I am getting this error:
[2024-04-29 05:55:42,126: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task scripttovideoapp.create_video[18288b91-d304-400a-97a9-285fac776f85] raised unexpected: OSError('MoviePy error: failed to read the duration of file https://delivery.gettyimages.com/downloads/1490392845?k=20&e=AnE-X_nyTRBG5QvUm1OnnCZEOURkdWAdDeQJTmDW8Eo41FL7u_ROCopEha5N-Kwh-fxBr44QIe5s2vzAUchlcVs91TwSlJTMOKWYSTraamKCPRcJv19CqNZRB_FgLaW_.\nHere are the file infos returned by ffmpeg:\n\nffmpeg version 4.2.2-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers\n  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)\n  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg\n  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100\n  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100\n  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100\n  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100\n  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100\n  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100\n  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100\n  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 285, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    line = [l for l in lines if keyword in l][index]
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 477, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 760, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/videoproj/scripttovideoapp.py", line 454, in create_video
    all_urls, video_details = process_script(script, paths, company_a, company_b, api_key)
  File "/home/ec2-user/videoproj/scripttovideoapp.py", line 232, in process_script
    video_duration = VideoFileClip(file).duration  # This needs to be replaced with a proper duration if available
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/VideoFileClip.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.reader = FFMPEG_VideoReader(filename, pix_fmt=pix_fmt,
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 35, in __init__
    infos = ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename, print_infos, check_duration,
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 289, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    raise IOError(("MoviePy error: failed to read the duration of file %s.\n"
OSError: MoviePy error: failed to read the duration of file https://delivery.gettyimages.com/downloads/1490392845?k=20&e=AnE-X_nyTRBG5QvUm1OnnCZEOURkdWAdDeQJTmDW8Eo41FL7u_ROCopEha5N-Kwh-fxBr44QIe5s2vzAUchlcVs91TwSlJTMOKWYSTraamKCPRcJv19CqNZRB_FgLaW_.
Here are the file infos returned by ffmpeg:

ffmpeg version 4.2.2-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100


I checked the version of my package on both mac and aws, the packages are the same. Went through different stackover flow solutions but non of them totally aligns with my issue.

Just a guess, but ffmpeg 4.2.2 is quite antiquated at this point (v7 just came out) so moviepy may not be compatible with the ffmpeg version this old. consider upgrading ffmpeg first.
